# Can the Mouse library scroll horizontally?

Tags: usb, linux, atmega32u4, mouse

I'm using the [Mouse](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseKeyboard) library with an ATmega32U4 connected to Linux via USB.

I would like to issue horizontal scroll commands, but the [Mouse.move()](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/MouseMove) function only seems to accept X movement, Y movement and vertical scroll parameters.

How can I send horizontal scroll commands from the Arduino to the computer?

Comment: You need to rewrite the core to provide buttons 6 and 7.

Comment: You could combine it with Keyboard to use the Ctrl and Shift keys for other scroll options.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in the comments, I edited the core libraries to achieve this.

I'm using [PlatformIO](http://platformio.org), so the library files I needed to edit were here:

```
~/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoavr/libraries/Mouse/src/
```

And the required changes (to change a `wheel` parameter for horizontal (`h`) and vertical (`v`) scroll parameters were as follows:

**Mouse.h**

Change the declaration of `move()`:

```
...
void move(signed char x, signed char y, signed char h = 0, signed char v = 0); 
...
```

**Mouse.cpp**

Add the following to the report descriptor after the last `INPUT` message:

```
...
0x05, 0x0c,        //       USAGE PAGE (Consumer Devices)
0x0a, 0x38, 0x02,  //       USAGE (AC Pan)
0x15, 0x81,        //       LOGICAL_MINIMUM (-127)
0x25, 0x7f,        //       LOGICAL_MAXIMUM (127)
0x75, 0x08,        //       REPORT_SIZE (8)
0x95, 0x01,        //       REPORT_COUNT (1)
0x81, 0x06,        //       INPUT (Data, Var, Rel)
...
```

Change the definition of `move()`:

```
void Mouse_::move(signed char x, signed char y, signed char h, signed char v)
{
    uint8_t m[5];
    m[0] = _buttons;
    m[1] = x;
    m[2] = y;
    m[3] = v;
    m[4] = h;
    HID().SendReport(1, m, 5);
}
```

---

The following terminal commands were also useful in testing these changes:

```
# List input devices
xinput --list

# List device capabilities
xinput --list <device-id>

# Watch for data sent from the device
watch -n 0.1 xinput query-state <device-id>
```

Comment: The NicoHood/HID library https://github.com/NicoHood/HID has a lot for keyboards (media keys and so on), but not everything for mice. I don't know if horizontal scrolling is somewhere in there.

Answer (score 0):

Horizontal Scroll is achieved by holding shift when scrolling vertically.

Do this instead:

```
Keyboard.press(KEY_LEFT_SHIFT);
    Mouse.move(0, 0, 1);
    Keyboard.releaseAll();
```